# Does drinking water from plastic bottles contaminate your blood?

Tags: chemistry, water

I wanted to know if there is any research on the issue Daniel Vitalis raises on bottling water [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lMs7iuY704) (5th minute and on). He claims that if one drinks water bottled in plastic bottles one will eventually have plastic in his blood. Another claim is that the superior way to transport your water is in a glass bottle ideally sealed with cork. Why cork?

On the same note, I've been told to sprout my seeds in a glass container.

All those may be true but with no further explanation, they are but empty claims. Could what he says about plastic bottles hold for glass bottles as well? Is it true for any clean, non-rusty bottle material? I wondered if anyone wants to address the issue, even if they wouldn't cite their sources.

p.s. Daniel Vitalis is a health food guru, specifically a water expert. He started the website "find a spring," and has countless of videos on water. He looks like no sort of a credible expert to me.

Comment: You need to focus the question on the claim that is being made (quote it or summarise it) to make a good question here. I have no idea what your claim is and I really don't want to have to read or watch any of the sites you linked to (fairly science illiterate at a glance). What does Vitalis claim in simple terms?

Comment: I watched the 5th minute. He doesn't seem to make any significant claims - he is just talking about a water bottle his brother gave him.

Comment: I wouldn't describe MMS as terribly controversial. Some pseudo-scientists promote it for sale. Scientists explain it is dangerous and that there isn't evidence for their claims, and that people are being injured using it. It is a simple, age-old story. [We've covered it all before.](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/119/what-is-miracle-mineral-solution-mms)

Comment: @matt_black Thank you, Mat. I'll be editing the question shortly.

Comment: @Oddthinking (I meant 5th minute and on.) One claim is that palastic bottles will "donate" some plastic to the water, hence to your blood, and glass bottles would not. Another claim is that your glass bottle should idealy be sealed with cork. I have been also told that when I sprout my seeds they should be in a glass container.

Comment: George, most of your question is just filler text. We don't need to know about your friend, or how convincing you find someone, or what you think of western medicine. Your question should take the simple format of: "Daniel Vitalis has produced several youtube videos in which he makes various claims about #####. I'm particularly skeptical of one claim where he states ###quote-exactly-what-he-says-in-the-video###. This quote can be heard at <##LINK##> at time index XX:XX. I am skeptical of this claim because ######." Keep it short, simple and clear.

Comment: "I wondered if anyone wants to address the issue, even if they wouldn't cite their sources." Sure! They can do that on *any* *other* site on the World Wide Web, but they may not do it here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is still a little broad:

> He claims that if one drinks water bottled in plastic bottles one will eventually have plastic in his blood.

This issue has already been addressed on this site:

- [Does regularly drinking from a plastic container cause cancer?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/does-regularly-drinking-from-a-plastic-container-cause-cancer/)
- [Does the container that soda is in affect the flavour?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3000/does-the-container-that-soda-is-in-affect-the-flavour/)
- [Do harmful chemicals migrate from the container into the food if you microwave the food in a plastic container?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8671/do-harmful-chemicals-migrate-from-the-container-into-the-food-if-you-microwave-t)

> Another claim is that the superior way to transport your water is in a glass bottle ideally sealed with cork. Why cork?

He doesn't explain (in the snippet I watched) what "superior" means or why it is superior. Without a scientific claim, he could be as simple as a fashion statement. (He seems to be proud of his unique glass bottle, and admits that glass bottles break all the time, but tries to turn that into a positive.)

> On the same note, I've been told to sprout my seeds in a glass container.

You have provided insufficient information about this claim to take a position. For example, the claim could be nothing to do with contaminants. It could be because the glass filters light differently, and (allegedly) promotes germination.

Comment: Hmmm... Perhaps this shouldn't be an answer, but an elaborate Close reason?

Comment: I'd rather have it here with this answer than close it. The question has improved since it was first posed and it is almost a useful one. Could be good with further editing and would point dodgy claims to useful answers.